# I want to read Mouse selected text from foreground window without using clipboard

Tags: delphi, winapi

Is there any windows application process interface to read selected/highlighted text from foreground window .

Comment: For which control(s) ?

Comment: ..., for rich edits `EM_GETSELTEXT` message.

Comment: For edits, you can use EM_GETSEL.

Comment: @David nope, all you need is the edit handle, nothing more,

Comment: OK, I stand corrected!

Answer (score 1):

The accessibility interfaces are provided for this purpose. There have been various such interfaces in the history of Windows. Today, the recommended API is [UI Automation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee684009.aspx). An overview can be found on MSDN: [Windows Automation API Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/dd561932.aspx).

Be prepared for the fact that not all controls in every application will submit to automation. In general it is probably impossible to expect to read text from every application in existence. However, well behaved applications will support automation.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but i didn't get what you mean to say . I was looking for a win-api to get selected text from foreground window to my delphi application. i have tried using wm_gettext but i am not able to get selected text. Can yo help me with some code example.

Comment: You asked if an interface to read highlighted texts exists. You did not ask for code. You asked a very general question, and got a correspondingly general answer. Now you need to spend some time trying to narrow down your problem and trying to solve it. If you get stuck on any specifics, do feel free to ask another question.