# how to read mouse selected word from foreground window in delphi without using clipboard

Tags: delphi, winapi

Can anyone give me code to read mouse selected or highlighted text from foreground window in delphi using any window api or anything else. 
here is my code i am sending keystroke ctrl+c to read to clipboard and then read from it

```
handltForForeGroundWindow := GetForegroundWindow ;
PostMessage(handltForForeGroundWindow , wm_keydown, VK_CONTROL, 0);
PostMessage(handltForForeGroundWindow , wm_keydown, VkKeyScan('c'), 0);
Sleep(40);
PostMessage(handltForForeGroundWindow , wm_keyup, VkKeyScan('c'), 0);
PostMessage(handltForForeGroundWindow , wm_keyup, VK_CONTROL, 0);
StoreWord := Clipboard.AsText;  // variable to read clipboard content
```

Comment: @DavidHeffernan : doesn't matter i use SendInput or PostMessage what i want to achieve is get text without clipboard like read it in some variable .

Comment: Have you considered that what your program does will be quite annoying? I mean if it interacts the foreground window without being instructed (most likely in a timer proc or a background loop) so it basically randomly overwrites the contents of the clipboard with random text (possibly garbage). I would feel really violated if I could not trust the clipboard during my everyday work. Not to mention your code will copy **anything** that is selected in the foreground window. Not only text, but files/bitmaps/etc.

Answer (score 0):

A critique of the code in the question:

1. `SendInput` is the correct API to use here. It places input messages into the queue of the active window. You can create an array of the four keyboard events, and put them into the queue in an atomic operation.
2. The call to `Sleep` is in the wrong place. Why wait before posting more input? That only increases the chance that somebody else will get in the way with some interfering input. Of course, that's exactly what `SendInput` is all about.
3. You will need to give the other application a chance to process the input. You'll have to wait after sending the input long enough for it to respond. How long will it need? Who can possibly say? This is the main weakness of your strategy. There's no reliable way for you to know how long you need to wait. Too short, and the app won't be done, too long and someone else (i.e. the user, who actually owns the clipboard) may well have overwritten the text you are looking for.
4. Destroying the user's clipboard is likely to make the users of your program hate it. I guess you know this already.

As to how to do this properly, without using the clipboard, well you really should be using the automation API for this task. That was the subject of your previous question: [I want to read Mouse selected text from foreground window without using clipboard](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25239900/) and I'm not sure quite what is different about this one.

Comment: can you be more specific about api and if you can share code that will be very helpful

Comment: My answer at the other question links to the documentation. You should start there.  If you want to find some example code to learn from all you need to do is a web search. If you don't want to use UI Automation then you can try an alternative method. UI Automation might not even be supported for your target application. Only you know that detail.